# What do the colors in the timeline render bar in After Effects signfify

Tags: after-effects

I have searched the web and PDF manual for clarification on what the colors signify on the render bar over the timeline in after effects but for some reason I cant find a resource covering them all.

Here's what I've found

- No Color - not rendered
- Green - rendered into RAM
- Blue - rendered into Global performance Cache

**My questions**

- Is this above correct?
- Are there any other colors? - *( I had thought there was a yellow and a red but I think these are used in Premiere Pro not After Effects )*

Comment: Yep yellow and red are Premiere. They signify footage that needs rendering that can and that can't be done in real time respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the information is correct, to be clear:

- Green cached on RAM
- Blue cached on disk

Pressing 0 on the num pad you will notice that on the blue line frames will render faster then on the none line.
Of course it will skip the green line because this process is called "Preview RAM" and as I have just said *Green* means written on the RAM.

No any other colours in AE.